# How to convert a pandas Dataframe into a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have seen a couple of example here, but none of it was on the point.

I have a data like

```
  countries:    usa    uk    germany   india    russia
   user :       aaa    bbb    ccc       ddd      eee
   visit:        50    20     9         30        58
```

So, I want to convert this df into a sparse martix like below:

```
          user       aaa      bbb      ccc        ddd       eee
 countries                                            
    usa               50        0         0        0          0 
    uk                 0        20        0        0          0 
   germany            0         0        9        0          0
   india              0         0        0        30         0 
   russia             0         0        0         0         58
```

P.S , there are also cases where there are user visitng multiple countries (for eg. zzz - 5 time russia and 4 time usa)

So I have tried multiple approx, but nothing work fine.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What approach have you tried?

Comment: I think you should provide the initial data as an actual DataFrame. Also the example should include the corner cases that you are describing in order to help to have a better understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting format the data is coming so I needed to do some transforming first.

```
d = ['countries','user','visit']
e = ['usa','aaa',50]
f= ['uk','bbb',20]
g = ['germany','ccc',9]
h = ['india','ddd',30]
i = ['russia','eee',58]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0:d,1:e,2:f,3:g,4:h,5:i})
           0    1    2        3      4       5
0  countries  usa   uk  germany  india  russia
1       user  aaa  bbb      ccc    ddd     eee
2      visit   50   20        9     30      58
```

Above resembles your starting format. In the next steps, I replace the columns with the country names, drop the first row (originally country names), and set the index to the first column.

```
df1.columns = df1.iloc[0].values
df1.drop(0, inplace=True)
df1.set_index('countries', inplace=True)
df1
           usa   uk germany india russia
countries
user       aaa  bbb     ccc   ddd    eee
visit       50   20       9    30     58
```

`Unstack` is where it starts to resemble the dataframes we're used to. Unstacking twice gives us record format. `Reset_index` gives something to pivot on, and `pivot` gets us the format. I then turn the dataframe into a sparse dataframe.

```
df1 = df1.unstack().unstack()
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1 = df1.pivot(index = 'index',columns = 'user', values = 'visit')
dfs = df1.to_sparse(fill_value = 0)

dfs
user     aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee
index
germany    0    0    9    0    0
india      0    0    0   30    0
russia     0    0    0    0   58
uk         0   20    0    0    0
usa       50    0    0    0    0

dfs.density
0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In short you shouldn't. Row names for data frames are better avoided. You should set "country", "user" and "visit count" as columns and add an observation for each tupple:

```
country, user, visit
usa    , aaa , x1
uk     , bbb , x2
```

Then if you want to know haw many times user u has visited country c in a dataframe df:
    df.loc[(df['user'] == u) & (df['country'] == c), 'visit'].iloc[0]

Comment: While this may be optimal approach, I do not think this answers OP's question ::))

Comment: I agree with you, I was just trying to spare future issues to the OP, my bad